# How to use indexOf (int ch) in java

Tags: java, string, indexof

I am trying to get the index number of a character in a string to divide the string into substrings.  Example:  I want to turn:

```
String book1 = "green eggs and ham, usa, dr. seuss";
```

into:

```
green eggs and ham
usa
dr. seuss
```

This has to work for strings of different lengths.  Basically, if I used different words it would still work.

I need help understanding the `indexOf()` method to get the index of the commas to put into a substring.

I have tried using variables in the method call after the `indexOf`, and I get errors when I use anything other than an int.

Comment: The `indexOf(int ch)` method returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified character in the string. So, it's not going to be helpful regarding what you are trying to achieve. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29

Answer (score 5):

I am not so sure of your actual requirement but you have quite a few options to try out:

- Use [`split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to split the string and store it as an array of String
- Use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to *tokenize* your String on a particular delimiter and use `nextToken()` to get the tokens. (*Note that StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code*)
- Third option would be to use regular expressions using [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Choose which ever is applicable to your requirement.

Comment: @PaulBellora: Thanks for reminding me of that. Updated my answer

Comment: The use of `StringTokenizer` is discouraged, it is only still available for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Use split.

```
"green eggs and ham, usa, dr. seuss".split(", ");
```

See: [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: As @MrLore indicated in a suggested edit, in this case the string should be split on `", "` - I rejected it only because it would have removed the link (concurrent edits issue).

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use it, the `split()` method is exactly what you need.

Otherwise, if you are required to only use `indexOf()`, look at the [Java API documentation for String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to understand how it works. The first thing I notice is that there are three different versions of `indexOf()`: [`indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29), [`indexOf(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29), and [`indexOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29). I believe the second of these will be the most applicable to this problem. Since the documentation states that this version of `indexOf()` "returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character, starting the search at the specified index," you will most likely need a loop of some kind in order to find every occurrence of a character.